# Inno Setup runhidden flag is not working for console application executed from batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd, console-application, inno-setup

I'm using Inno Setup to make installer for my Django webapp created using PyInstaller. Since my application needs a command (command-line console application) to run a server, I wrote a batch script to accomplish that. My problem is I don't want to show console window to end user, I want to make it hidden.

Inno Setup .iss file:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\cookie_dot.bat"; Description: "Start server"; \
    Flags: nowait postinstall runhidden skipifsilent
```

But it still shows a console window.

For more details, my batch file:

```bat
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\cookie_dot\wkhtmltopdf.exe
START "" "http://localhost:88/"
START "" "C:\cookie_dot\cookie_dot.exe" runserver localhost:88
```

Comment: Sorry @MartinPrikryl This Is created using Wizard, ill post the full and new iss file

Comment: Please have a look on my new edits @MartinPrikryl

Comment: What is `cookie_dot.exe`? Is that a console application?

Comment: Yes @MartinPrikrylits , its a web app from that i made exe(Django app collected using pyinstaller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `runhidden` hides a console window of the batch file (`cmd.exe`).

But you start yet another console application (`cookie_dot.exe`) in a separate console window (due to the `start` command).

*Note that if you remove the `runhidden` flag, you will get two console windows (though the first one shows just briefly, while the batch file is running).*

---

You do not need to use the `start` command for `cookie_dot.exe`, as you use `nowait` flag, so Inno Setup won't mind that the (hidden) batch file stays running as long as the `cookie_dot.exe` runs:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\cookie_dot\wkhtmltopdf.exe
START "" "http://localhost:88/"
"C:\cookie_dot\cookie_dot.exe" runserver localhost:88
```

Without the `start` command, the `cookie_dot.exe` inherits the hidden console window of the batch file (`cmd.exe`).

Comment: When i executed the EXE file Two applications are running in background its using lot of memories too, Any idea why application running in background two times ?

Comment: What "exe"? `cookie_dot.exe` itself? Or the installer?

Comment: Then I do not see how this is related to this question. If you have a new problem, please ask it separately. This is Q&A site, not a discussion forum.